# How to let fscanf stop reading after a new line

Tags: scanf

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MAX 1000

int line_counter (FILE *file, char buf[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *ptr_file; 
    char buf[MAX];
    ptr_file = fopen("alice-eg.txt", "r");

    if (!ptr_file) {
        return 1;
    } 

    int count = 0;

    while (fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", buf) == 1) {
        printf("%s", buf);
        if (buf == '\n') {
            return count;
        }
        else {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The number of words in this line is: %d", count);
    return 0;    
}
```

I want to do something along the lines of this but I have no idea how to make it work as the buf is just a pointer to an array of letters (correct me if I'm wrong I just started with C and my understanding of pointers is still quite bad).

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` write the line from the file (separated by ENTER) to the buff array and so if it will read an empty line `buff[0] = '\n'` so that should be your condition.

Secondly:

```
while (fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", buf) == 1)
```

Is wrong since fscanf returns the number of read character and so for the line "abcd" form the file it will return 4 and your loop will stop right away instead of reading the entire file and so your condition should be:

```
while (fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", buf) != EOF)
```

since fscanf will return EOF when it will reach the end of the file

Comment: why would the fscanf read characters? I thought that it would reader words in each sentence?

Comment: Because you gave it "%s" means one string, it you give it "%s %s" it will split the line in the first space and will return 2 strings but for that you need to write fscanf(ptr_file, "%s %s", str1, str2), please read the fscanf docs.